# WP Power Tool does not show any emulator or device

Tags: visual-studio-2015, emulation, windows-10-mobile, visual-studio-power-tools

I'm working on Windows 10 Mobile. And when I use WP Power Tool to get the database from Emulator. I've got this problem: the WP Power Tool does not show the emulator to connect. [image]
I downloaded the WP Power Tool from https://wptools.codeplex.com
Please help me.. Thanks a lot.

**Update**
I want that it works like that[image: WP Power Tool works well with my friends]

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like there is a windows 10 mobile version of the phone power tools available

The last release I see on CodePlex for the tools is Windows Phone Power Tools 2.83 for WP 8.1

Last check in for the windows phone power tools on CodePlex and GitHub was in Aug 2014

Answer (score -1):

Remove `11.0` or `10.0` at:

```
C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\PhoneTools\CoreCon
```